# iphone - Check if an app is installed

Tags: iphone, list, sample

I want to bring the list of what apps are installed in my iPhone.

I hear this code sample is in this website but I can't find it.

Code Sample: Check if an app is installed - iDevKit:
http://idevkit.com/forums/tutorials-code-samples-sdk/604-code-sample-check-if-app-installed.html

Can anyone give me a hint or how to get that code from the website?

Thanks.

Comment: Swift-solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53852623/how-to-get-the-list-of-applications-suitable-for-routing-from-the-user-s-device

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible on non-jailbroken iOS devices—the app sandbox prevents it. You can test for some individual applications, if you know the URL schemes they implement (e.g. `tel://` for the Phone app), by calling `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"someScheme://blah"]]`, but if an app doesn’t respond to any URL schemes then you’re not going to be able to determine whether it’s present on the device.

Answer (score 0):

On a jailbroken device you can check against the apps binary:

```
-(BOOL)isWrightsCSInstalled
{
    return [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:@"/Applications/WrightsCS.app/WrightsCS"];
}
```

Or, if you know the app has a custom URL Schema you can check if the URL can be opened:

```
- (BOOL) isTwitterInstalled 
{
    if ( [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"twitter://"]] )
        return YES;
    else
        return NO;
}
```