# How to find out how the `Music App` is installed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios13

My app imports music from the `Music app` via `MPMediaPickerController`. A modal will appear even if the user has deleted the music app. However, if it was deleted in iOS13, the modal no longer appears. So I want to check if the `Music app` is installed. I tried the following code and confirmed that YES is returned even if it is not installed.

```c
- (BOOL)isInstalledMusicApp
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"music://"];
    return [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: url];
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check app is installed or not in phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41545283/how-to-check-app-is-installed-or-not-in-phone)

Comment: @inexcitus Thanks for your comment. I think this code is the same as the linked one. Even if it is not installed, YES is returned.

Comment: You are right, no matter whether you install `Music app ` , `canOpenURL` always returns `YES`. But I found in the test that when I use `canOpenURL`, will prompt `Restore "Music"`. If you don't have Pop up, you can consider whether it is in the main thread

Comment: If you still want to know if it is installed, you can use `[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL` directly, `completionHandler` will return the result.

Comment: @Nullable Thank you for the advice. I'll do my best with this hint!