# How to check if an iOS app is installed without canOpenURL

Tags: ios, swiftui

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41545283/how-to-check-app-is-installed-or-not-in-phone/4154541) to verify if an app is installed "some.bundle.id://" scheme and canOpenURL technique can be used.

However, I've discovered in SwiftUI 5 and iOS 14.1 that it doesn't always work, e.g.

```
// Works    
UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string: "com.garmin.connect.mobile://")!)  

// Doesn't work
UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string: "com.fitbit.FitbitMobile://")!)
```

I've found the error below in Mac's Console App log connected to iPhone. Looks like Fitbit app is blocking the queries:

```
default 12:03:34.339735-0700    2fahub  -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "FitbitMobile://app" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme fitbitmobile"
```

While in my Xcode's debug window I can see this:

```
2021-05-30 12:46:16.416998-0700 2fahub[588:100068] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "com.fitbit.FitbitMobile://" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)"
```

In my app query permissions are set correctly

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>com.garmin.connect.mobile</string>
    <string>com.fitbit.FitbitMobile</string>
</array>
```

What else can be used to make sure that it always works? Is there anything similar to Android's PackageManager API in iOS?

Update #1:

Actually the answer provided by Fitbit forum was correct. The scheme for Fitbit must be "fitbit://" and it's absolutely not clear why, given that bundle ID for this app is com.fitbit.FitbitMobile. 'fitbit' is not the app name, neither it's the whole bundle ID. In Garmin case I must use the whole bundle ID to make it working. Would be good to know what the rules really are here. What should I do if need to add more apps to verify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems the Fitbit's URL Scheme is not `com.fitbit.FitbitMobile://`(this is it's bundle id)\

Try with **`fitbit://`**

These two posts seem to have it working 
[Answer from 2016 - community.fitbit.com](https://community.fitbit.com/t5/Web-API-Development/URL-to-Open-Fitbit-iOS-and-Android-Apps/td-p/1527027#:%7E:text=thanks.%20i%20was%20able%20to%20get%20it%20to%20work%20with%20this%20url%20schema%20on%20ios.)
[Answer from 2020 - community.fitbit.com](https://community.fitbit.com/t5/Web-API-Development/Open-fitbit-app-from-another-iPhone-app-URL-scheme/td-p/4478671#:%7E:text=i%20found%20the%20answer.%20url%20scheme%20fitbit%3A%2F%2F%20works%20for%20me)

Comment: Thank you. "fitbit://" worked but it's absolutely not clear why given that fitbit is not the app name, nor the whole bundle ID. Please vote to reopen, because other refs were absolutely pointless

Comment: **fitbit** is the URL Scheme putting the bundle ID or the app name on LSApplicationQueriesSchemes simply won't work,
[LSApplicationQueriesSchemes - Summary](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html#:~:text=specifies%20the%20url%20schemes%20the%20app%20is%20able%20to%20test%20using%20the%20canopenurl).
There is a good posibility that garmin set it's URL Scheme and bundle ID as **com.garmin.connect.mobile**