# How to get the list of applications suitable for routing from the user’s device?

Tags: swift, maps, ios11

Is there any way to check if user has a certain app (google.maps, yandex.maps or native maps) on his/her device to make a list of apps suitable for routing?

Comment: No you cant do this! Imagine this would be possible: Apps could use this information as unique identifier for your iOS Device and could sell this data to make money for adds and something like this. Conclusion: Luckily for privacy reasons this is not possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iphone - Check if an app is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854362/iphone-check-if-an-app-is-installed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if user has this apps on device (google.maps, yandex.maps or native maps) using URL scheme.

for Google maps:

`let appURL = URL(string: “comgooglemaps://”)
if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(appURL!) {
    // code for open URL
    print(“Can Open URL”)
}`